# How to know radio buttons of list-group not checked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am creating website to take test. In that I gave question & 4 radio buttons for options.
I am getting checked options using this snippet:

```
const formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('form'));
let checkvalues = []
for (const value of formData.values()) {
   checkvalues.push(value)
}
```

But what happened is, suppose out of four radio buttons none of them is selected, then
I do not get any blank/null value for it.
So, how to know radio buttons of list-group not checked or is there any option like defaultvalue if not selected?

**test.js**

```
var data = [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "question" : "jvm is____________",
        "options" : [
            "platform dependant",
            "platform lndepedent",
            "depends on jvm implementation",
            "Both b and c"
        ],
        "answer" : "platform dependant"
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "question" : "return type of main method is______",
        "options" : [
            "int",
            "char",
            "void",
            "None of the above"
        ],
        "answer" : "void"
    }
]
```

**index.html**

```
<p id="result" class="m-3"></p>
<form id="form">
<div id="test" class="card-body"></div>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center mb-5">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
        $("#form").submit((event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            onTimesUp()
            submit()
        }
        )

        function submit() {
            $(".list-group-item").addClass('disabled')
            const formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('form'));
            let checkvalues = []
            let result = []
            for (const value of formData.values()) {
                checkvalues.push(value)
            }
            for (const key of formData.keys()) {
                console.log(key)
            }
            var i = 0;
            var sum = 0;
            data.map((que) => {
                if (que.answer === checkvalues[i]) {
                    sum += 1;
                    $(`#answer${i + 1}`).addClass('text-success').html('Right answer');
                }
                else {
                    $(`#answer${i + 1}`).addClass('text-danger').html(`Wrong answer.<p class='text-success mb-1'> Right answer : ${que.answer}</p>`);
                }
                i++
            })

            $("#result").html(`Your score : ${sum}/${data.length}`)
            $("#result").show()
        }

        $(window).on('load', function () {
            $("#result").hide()
            $("#answer").hide()
            data.map((que) => {
                $("#test").append(`
                <div class="card mb-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card mb-2">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <p>Q.${que.id} ${que.question}</p>
                            </div>                           
                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="radio" name="listGroupRadio${que.id}" value="${que.options[0]}" id="firstRadio">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="firstRadio">${que.options[0]}</label>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="radio" name="listGroupRadio${que.id}" value="${que.options[1]}" id="secondRadio">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="secondRadio">${que.options[1]}</label>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="radio" name="listGroupRadio${que.id}" value="${que.options[2]}" id="thirdRadio">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="secondRadio">${que.options[2]}</label>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <input class="form-check-input me-1" type="radio" name="listGroupRadio${que.id}" value="${que.options[3]}" id="fourthRadio">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="secondRadio">${que.options[3]}</label>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <p id='answer${que.id}' class='mt-2 mb-1'></p>
                    </div>
                </div>               
                `)
            })

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: With radio buttons it's best practice to set a default value by setting the `checked` attribute on one of the inputs. `<input type="radio" name="foo" checked />`

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Thanks bro! I have added one hidden list-group-item with checked radio button, that solve my problem.                                                                           
<li class="list-group-item" hidden>
<input class="form-check-input me-1" type="radio" name="listGroupRadio${que.id}" value="null" id="firstRadio${que.id}" checked>
</li>

Comment: That's one way to fix it. However it would recommend making your inputs `required`. That way the user is obligated to choose an option. Otherwise they'll won't be able to submit.

Comment: It's time based test, so user can unattempt the question.